# using Entity framework code first with an IOC container for creating entities without a default constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I want to build an entity framework code first datalayer that encrypts some of its properties. For that an `ICryptographer` should be injected when creating an instance with data loaded from the database.

Is it possible to inject `ICryptographer` using a IOC Container such like unity?

**DAL example:**

```
public class context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Credentials> Credentials {get;set;}
}

public CredentialsConfiguration()
{
    ToTable("Profiles");
    HasKey(p => p.ProfileName);
    Ignore(p => p.SecretKey);
    Ignore(p => p.AccessKey);
    Property(p => p._accessKey)
        .HasColumnName("AccessKey");
    Property(p => p._secretKey)
        .HasColumnName("SecretKey");
}
```

**Common Entities Assembly: (with internals visible to DAL)**

```
public class Credentials
{
    private readonly ICryptographer _cryptographer;

    public Credentials(ICryptographer cryptographer)
    {
        _cryptographer = cryptographer;
    }


    internal string _accessKey { get; set; }
    public string AccessKey
    {
        get { return _cryptographer.Decrypt(_accessKey); }
        set { _accessKey = _cryptographer.Encrypt(value); }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give more details on why you want to do this.  This page might point you in the right direction, boils down to using `OnEntityMaterialized` to inject the correct services http://rogeralsing.com/2009/05/30/entity-framework-4-entity-dependency-injection/

Comment: The software registers an AWS profile on the machine where the software is started but I don't want my keys stored in plain text in my database.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very contrived example but might push you into the right direction

We need a way to know when to inject a property into the entity class, as such they are marked using

```
public interface ICryptographerUser {
    ICryptographer Cryptographer { get; set; }
}
```

Where `ICryptographer` is defined as

```
public interface ICryptographer {
    string Decrypt(string value);
    string Encrypt(string value);
}
```

The instance that will be injected is defined as

```
public class Cryptographer : ICryptographer {
    public string Decrypt(string value) {
        return "Decrypted";
    }

    public string Encrypt(string value) {
        return "Encrypted";
    }
}
```

When adding an entity we need to make use  of a `Factory` that is cognizant of the fact that we need to inject properties (You can make use of IOC to do this)

```
public static class EntityFactory {
    public static T CreateInstance<T> () {
        var entity = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        if (entity is ICryptographerUser) {
            //INJECT INSTANCE HERE
            (entity as ICryptographerUser).Cryptographer = new Cryptographer();
        }

        return entity;
    }      
}
```

Now to add and entity we can just use

```
var entity = EntityFactory.CreateInstance<Credentials>();
        entity.SetAccessKey("123");
        entity.SecretKey = "456";
        entity.ProfileName = "a";

        contect.Set<Credentials>().Add(entity);
```

When objects are queried from `Context` the following code will inject the objects, but this is done after their respective properties has already been set

```
public MyContext() {
        IObjectContextAdapter objectContextAdapter = (this as IObjectContextAdapter);
        objectContextAdapter.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged += ObjectStateManager_ObjectStateManagerChanged;
    }

    private void ObjectStateManager_ObjectStateManagerChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CollectionChangeEventArgs e) {
        // we are only interested in entities that
        // have been added to the state manager
        if (e.Action != CollectionChangeAction.Add)
            return;

        IObjectContextAdapter objectContextAdapter = (this as IObjectContextAdapter);

        var state = objectContextAdapter.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(e.Element).State;

        // we are only interested in entities that
        // are unchanged (that is; loaded from DB)
        if (state != EntityState.Unchanged)
            return;

        OnObjectMaterialized(e.Element);
    }

    private void OnObjectMaterialized(object e) {
        if (e is ICryptographerUser) {
            //INJECT INSTANCE HERE
            (e as ICryptographerUser).Cryptographer = new Cryptographer();
        }      
    }
```

As the instance will only be injected after the `Entity` has been materialized I needed to modify your `Entity` definition as follows

```
public class Credentials : ICryptographerUser {
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }

    internal string _secretKey { get; set; }
    internal string _accessKey { get; set; }


    public string SecretKey { get; set; }

    public string AccessKey {
        get { return _accessKey; }
        private set { _accessKey = value; }
    }

    public string AccessKeyDecrypted {
        get { return Cryptographer.Decrypt(_accessKey); }
    }

    public void SetAccessKey(string value) {
        _accessKey = Cryptographer.Encrypt(value);
    }

    public ICryptographer Cryptographer { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `AccessKey` has `private set { _accessKey = value; }` which allows `EF` to set the property when the `object` materializes but when you set the property value you must call `public void SetAccessKey(string value)` which makes use of `Cryptographer` to encrypt the field.